# Validation for form with dynamic parts

Tags: angular

i have a question about form validation with formgroup.
A part of my form is dynamic (call of other components).

This is my form:

```
            <form [formGroup]="deliveryService.deliveryForm" >
            <!--Common input field-->
            <div #name class="QTZ_form_group QTZ_valid">
                <div class="QTZ_form_dropdown">
                    <label class="QTZ_prepend_input">
                        Name
                        <span>
                            <input [(ngModel)]="deliveryService.deliveryModel.name" type="text" name="name">
                        </span>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!--Dynamic part from other component-->
            <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="currentComponent"></ng-container>


            <div class="QTZ_form_controls">
                <button class="QTZ_primary_bg" (click)="onSubmit()" [disabled]="!deliveryService.deliveryForm.valid">Validate</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

In this form i have a dynamic part (other component injected) with ngComponentOutlet.
These component are part of the form but are not calling all the time

What is my best option for used my formGroup with the other component.

Thanks you for your help

Answer (score 0):

I would not make your child component dynamic, but rather instantiate it in the form without the ng-container and simply pass it the parent form data as a binding.  If you are using a reactive form, it will automatically get any form data from the child components and use it to populate the parent form schema.  Validation can then be provided by the reactive form schema.

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [formGroup]="myForm">
    <myFormChildComponent [parent]="myForm"></myFormChildComponent>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks you for your idea but i cant change the form method and i cant used reactive form :(. there is any solution for save my structure and just made validation to works with it?

Comment: I'm less familiar with template driven forms, but I believe that my previous suggestion will work the same way, you'll just need to handle the validation on the HTML side rather than in the form schema.  Using either form type, I would still remove the ngComponentOutlet and just pass the form data through the [parent] binding of the child component.

Comment: Okay so i have tried your solution but i have an error.
Can't bind to 'parent' since it isn't a known property of 'app-external-form-1'.

this is the stackblitz url 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bxzyhf

Can you help me to understand why parent seems to not work ?

Comment: Do you have an input on your child component to accept the [parent] form binding?  It needs to be in the form of: @Input(‘parent’) parent: any;

Comment: Yes i have try but the validation not work :(.
if the child is not load (because its not load every time) The form is invalid